# DraftJS: Reset blockType after return

Tags: draftjs

I am currently building an editor like the one that is used on medium.com. For each `unstyled` block, I render a custom component that holds edit buttons to change the block type of that section.

However, when I for example change the section to a `header-one` and hit the return button the new block is also a `header-one` block. I like to see that the new block is `unstyled` instead of the same type of the previous block.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: You just saved me so much time. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

After some more searching and trying I found the solution myself! It appears that the best way to do this is by inserting a new block when the split-block keyCommand is fired.

For example:

```js
createEmptyBlock(editorState: Draft.EditorState) {
    const newBlock = new Draft.ContentBlock({
        key: Draft.genKey(),
        type: "unstyled",
        text: "",
        characterList: Immutable.List()
    })

    const contentState = editorState.getCurrentContent()
    const newBlockMap = contentState.getBlockMap().set(newBlock.getKey(), newBlock)

    return Draft.EditorState.push(
        editorState,
        Draft.ContentState
            .createFromBlockArray(newBlockMap.toArray())
            .set('selectionAfter', contentState.getSelectionAfter().merge({
                anchorKey: newBlock.getKey(),
                anchorOffset: 0,
                focusKey: newBlock.getKey(),
                focusOffset: 0,
                isBackward: false,
            })) as Draft.ContentState,
        "split-block"
    )
}
```

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/49453635/2) to the question [DraftJS: Reset blockType after return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49453635/draftjs-reset-blocktype-after-return) by the OP [n9iels](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4703833/n9iels) under CC BY-SA 3.0.</sub>